# Opencv with cuda GpuMat::create() call causes access violation

Tags: c++, opencv

I compiled (debug and release) opencv 4.1.0 with contrib modues and enabled cuda.

I'm trying to create a GpuMat and upload host data from cv::Mat.

This works properly when running in debug mode. However when I run in release mode (even when turning off optimizations) I get an access violation in the GpuMat::create() function (gpu_mat.cu line 174):

```
bool allocSuccess = allocator->allocate(this, rows, cols, esz);
```

"Exception thrown: read access violation.
this->allocator was 0x21A."

My code for creating the GpuMat:

```
cv::Mat raw = cv::Mat(inImg->height, inImg->width, CV_16UC1, inImg->host_data);
g_inImg.create(inImg->height, inImg->width, CV_16UC1);
```

The crash is only happens in Release mode.

Do anyone has  a clue what could be the reason?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am having a similar issue in both Debug and Release x64. What do your project properties look like for both Debug and Release? I'm hoping that there's a minor difference that will solve both of our problems.